# \makecell align does not work?

Tags: makecell

In the docs of the [makecell package](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf) in Section 1.1 it stated that one can align text horizontally to the top or bottom with `\makecell[t]{..}` and `\makecell[b]{..}`. I tried that with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{  l | l l l}

 & Leistung & Stunden & Preis \\
\hline
1. Webdesign &  \makecell[l]{asdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d
 \\ asdada sdasdasdasd \\ sdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d
 \\ asdada sdasdasdasd \\ sdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas 
 d \\ asdada sdasdasdasd} 
 & \makecell[t]{Should be top} & \makecell[b]{6Should be bottom}  \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But it does not work. There is no horizontally alignment happening. Why? Thats the result:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Your interpretation of the *vertical* alignment specification is incorrect. Using a `[t]`op alignment merely sets the *anchor* point for that specific cell to the baseline of the `t`op\first line of the cell content. Similarly, a `[b]`ottom alignment sets the *anchor* point to the baseline of `b`ottom/last line. This doesn't mean that the cell content will be pushed down/up to align with surrounding cells. So

```
\makecell[t]{%
  one \\% This will be the anchor point
  two \\
  three
}
```

while

```
\makecell{%
  one \\
  two \\% This will be the anchor point
  three
}
```

and

```
\makecell[b]{%
  one \\
  two \\
  three% This will be the anchor point
}
```

Here I've highlighted the anchor points to show how they are vertically aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \makecell[t]{one \\ two \\ three} &
  \makecell   {one \\ two \\ three} &
  \makecell[b]{one \\ two \\ three}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

We should be able to gather a number of things from this:

1. You're specifying an *anchor* point, not really a vertical alignment with respect to other cells.
2. The anchor is associated with the `\makecell` in question, not other cells within the same row.
3. You can only specify *one* anchor per cell.

In your example you actually want multiple alignments with column `Leistung` (`[t]`op with respect to `Stunden` and `[b]`ottom with respect to `Preis`), and alignments of columns `Studen` and `Preis` have no preference since they are only a single line; that is, their vertical *anchor* will just be the line they're on.

Considering your setup, you can move content up/down using boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\cellbox}
\savebox{\cellbox}{%
  \makecell[l]{%
    asdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d \\
    asdada sdasdasdasd \\
    sdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d \\
    asdada sdasdasdasd \\
    sdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d \\
    asdada sdasdasdasd}
}%
\begin{tabular}{ l | l l l }
  \hline
  1. Webdesign &
    \usebox{\cellbox} &
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\cellbox-\height}{\makecell{Should be top}} &
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\ht\cellbox-.5\dp\cellbox+.5\normalbaselineskip}{\makecell{Should be bottom}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that the anchor points for all cells still remain in the middle (vertically) of each cell.

Answer (score 3):

A work-around consists in adding empty lines. I took the opportunity to add some padding to the cells with `\makegapedcells`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{ l | l l l}
 & Leistung & Stunden & Preis \\
\hline
1. Webdesign & \makecell[l]{asdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d
 \\ asdada sdasdasdasd \\ sdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d
 \\ asdada sdasdasdasd \\ sdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas
 d \\ asdada sdasdasdasd}
 & \makecell{Should be top\\\\\\\\\\\\} & \makecell{\\\\\\\\\\6Should be bottom} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following example, the two alignment labels `[t]`, `[b]` already work but only if you add more lines of text and the alignment is relative to the first column. This is because you didn't provide a label to `makecell` in the big cell in second column, so it is vertically centered by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}    

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{  l | l l l}
 & Leistung & Stunden & Preis \\
\hline
1. Webdesign &  \makecell[l]{asdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d
 \\ asdada sdasdasdasd \\ sdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas d
 \\ asdada sdasdasdasd \\ sdads asd asd ada dadadas dasdas 
 d \\ asdada sdasdasdasd} 
 & \makecell[t]{Should be top\\and is really top} & \makecell[b]{6Should be bottom\\and is still bottom}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]